# How to restructure code so it doesn't use a storyboard in Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisearchcontroller

The problem Im having is probably a quite easy fix, however, I am fairly new to Swift and I can't seem to make this work.

I have ben having a lot of trouble with a UISearchController, Ive been trying for the last few days to build one that works with no success, now I have been given some code that looks like it should work however one line uses an `@IBOutlet` which i believe is a storyboard/interfacebuilder piece of code.

Is there a way to rewrite this line so that it doesn't use an `@IBOutlet`? as it makes my app crash when i load the view. Here is the line that I am stuck with:

`@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!`

and here is the code for the whole controller:

```
class DemoSearchController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let data = ["New York, NY", "Los Angeles, CA", "Chicago, IL", "Houston, TX",
        "Philadelphia, PA", "Phoenix, AZ", "San Diego, CA", "San Antonio, TX",
        "Dallas, TX", "Detroit, MI", "San Jose, CA", "Indianapolis, IN",
        "Jacksonville, FL", "San Francisco, CA", "Columbus, OH", "Austin, TX",
        "Memphis, TN", "Baltimore, MD", "Charlotte, ND", "Fort Worth, TX"]

    var filteredData: [String]!

    var searchController: UISearchController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        filteredData = data

        // Initializing with searchResultsController set to nil means that
        // searchController will use this view controller to display the search results
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        // If we are using this same view controller to present the results
        // dimming it out wouldn't make sense.  Should set probably only set
        // this to yes if using another controller to display the search results.
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        // Sets this view controller as presenting view controller for the search interface
        definesPresentationContext = true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableCell") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filteredData.count
    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text

        filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? data : data.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
            return dataString.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
        })

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

}

Is there a solution to this? If so, how would I go about implementing it?

I'm having so much trouble with the new UISearchController

Comment: If you aren't assigning a table view from a storyboard then you will need to allocate a tableview instance in code and add it to your view

Comment: Rebind your `UITableview` from `UIStoryboard`, it may has not bound properly.

Comment: You should probably also get the storyboard from the place you got your code. This code is making a reference to `UITableView` from StoryBoard file.

Comment: @Paulw11 How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @sasquatch I'm not using storyboards, thats's the issue

Comment: Then make an instance of tableView in your code, and assign the var to it.

Comment: @Addzy you say you are new to Swift. Are you also new to iOS development in general?  If so the I suggest you look for some tutorials on creating your UI in code or consider using storyboards. If you are just learning app development you are taking on a lot more to create your UI in code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Storyboard, then remove the `IBOutlet`.
Instead you can create an instance of `UITableView` in your code.

`var tableView = UITableView()`

Then it would not try to find the referenced tableView from IB.

You will also have to set the frame for the tableView, you can do it in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 100, 400, 200) //x,y,width,height
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}
```

Comment: Aha thank you, that got me a little bit further, however when the controller loads you can just see the navigation bar and then the rest is black, any ideas on why this is?

Comment: @sasquatch Having created the tableview you will need to set it's frame, or set some constraints and add it as a sub view to the view controller's view - I would suggest you show these steps in your answer

Comment: You are also dequeueing cell with identifier without registering it anywhere.
Use `func registerClass(_ cellClass: AnyClass,
forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String) ` to register your class first before dequeueing